# Meteor: How to call a server method which is independent of client and call it at regular interval?

Tags: meteor

I have a method that needs to be run only in the server (independent of client) and i want to run that method at regular intervals.  This method calls 2 api's and upsert data into into db. Can anybody please clarify below doubts ?

1. do i have to write my method inside Meteor.method ?

   Meteor.Method({ myMethod: function() {.....}   });
2. Do i have to use setInterval inside Meteor.method itself ?
3. Do i have to write the my code inside Meteor.startup ?
4. As my task is pretty simple i.e calling external api's(dependent api for eg : first api provides student username and second api student details), is it fine to use just setInterval or should i use any metoer pacakge ?
5. How do i implement upsert in meteor ? its a very simple usert where i need to see if username already exist in db. if not, insert otherwise update.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes write the method like that.
2. You can call the method inside the server like this:

   `Meteor.setInterval(function() {
   Meteor.call('yourMethod', arg1, arg2
   }, 5000)`

This code should be then inside /server folder or wrapped into

```
`if (Meteor.isServer) {

}`
```

This should do it.

3. No
4. start with interval and see?
5. You can read about upsert here http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/upsert